# make simple jQuery image Slider with next, prev button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Someone can help me add next and prev button for this slider. I found this code in blog,...
Here, this code http://jsfiddle .net/dk5sy93d/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dk5sy93d/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the JS for your HTML.

http://jsbin.com/nalewayume/1/edit?js,console,output

```
function nextSlide() {
  if(currentSlide < allSlides) {        
      $slide.eq(currentSlide).fadeOut(200);      
      $slide.eq(currentSlide + 1).fadeIn(200);        
      currentSlide+=1;   
  }
}
```

Comment: If you want a more advanced slide you should take a look at owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/

Answer (score 2):

I'm new to Jquery (since yesterday). I have to make a simple slider in an upcoming web development competition. This is just something I wrote because everything I seem to come across has a large library attached to it.

```js
//Manual Slider Control Jquery

$("#slider-next").click(function(){
 if($(".slider-a").is(":visible")){
  $(".slider-a").hide(3000);
 }else{
  $(".slider-b").hide(3000);
 }         
});

$("#slider-prev").click(function(){
 if(($(".slider-a").not(":visible")) && ($(".slider-b").is(":visible"))){
  $(".slider-a").show(3000);
 }else if(($(".slider-a").not(":visible")) && ($(".slider-b").not(":visible"))){
  $(".slider-b").show(3000);
 }
});
```

```css
/* Slider CSS */
#slider-container{
    margin:auto;
    text-align:center;
}
#slider-content{
    margin:auto;
    height:300px;
    width:400px;
    overflow:hidden;
    border:2px solid #000;
    background-color:grey;
}
#slider-controls{
    margin:auto;
    text-align:center;
    width:400px;
}
#slider-controls button{
    background-color:#000;
    padding:0 15px;
    font-size:1em;
    border-radius: 0 0 15px 15px;
    color:white;
}
#slider-prev{
    float:left;
}
#slider-next{
    float:right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slider-container">
    <div id="slider-content">
        <img class="slider-img slider-a" src="http://www.light2015.org/.imaging/stk/pop/zoom/dam/CosmicLight/A-Universe-of-Images/Vela_Supernova_Remnant/jcr:content/Vela_Supernova_Remnant.2014-07-17-20-32-16.png" width="400px" height="300px" />
        <img class="slider-img slider-b" src="http://www.sciuridae.co.uk/photography/images/blown_out_skies/two_images.jpg" width="400px" height="300px" />
        <img class="slider-img clider-c" src="http://www1.hw.ac.uk/estate/images/landscape-images/cycleways-and-footpaths-big.JPG" width="400px" height="300px" />
    </div>
    <div id="slider-controls">
        <button id="slider-prev">Previous</button>
        <button id="slider-next">Next</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please comment on this answer if you feel it can be simplified further and offer the same (if not improved) functionality.

Comment: Added show() / hide() to the control buttons to hide 'prev' on first image and hide 'next' on last image.